# "Allow executing file as a program" checks itself

Tags: permissions

I am a beginner with Ubuntu. I have version 16.04. I have searched through similar questions but was unable to find an answer.

This question is concerned with the type of text file you get when you right-click in a folder and select NEW DOCUMENT > EMPTY DOCUMENT. I'm calling these 'text files' but they don't end with .txt. In fact, they have no extension at all. When I double-click on said newly created document, it opens with gedit.

My issue is this - some time after I create one of these text files, and I try to open it by double-clicking on it, it won't open until I uncheck the "Allow executing file as a program" checkbox, which I didn't check. I'm not sure when this checkbox checks itself.

I don't create executable files as I'm just not that advanced. I would prefer it if the default was unchecked and I can check it if I ever need to create an executable. Is there a way to tell the system to never check this box unless it's done manually?

Comment: Are you creating these files on an external filesystem (such as NTFS) that does not implement Unix file permissions?

Comment: When you uncheck the box, does it stay unchecked? (This may be related to what steeldriver said.)

Comment: The nonsensical default now for udisks2 is to mount all files on ntfs volumes as executable, this carries over when they are copied to an ext2/4 volume.

Comment: I am creating these files on an ext4 partition. I have a 700GB hard drive divided into 3 - a 512 MB boot sector (fat 32), 690 GB on ext4 and a 7.2GB partition with "Linux-swap" filesystem. I got this information using GParted. I am not sure if the checkbox remains unchecked once I check it